# MSSQL peer to peer replication what is the best practice to drop and create multiple table

Tags: sql-server, replication

I have a Transactional Replication server in peer to peer topology with 3 server node.
My development strategy was Agile, so that will be a frequency change on the database etc.

Scenario: I need to drop 20 tables out of 100 tables, and create another 30 tables at a time.
May I know what is the best/common practice to do it?

What I can think of was,

1. Drop all replication article and subscription for 3 server node.
2. Drop the 20 tables and create the 30 tables on each server node.
3. Resetup back the peer to peer topology replication to the 3 server node.

(P/S: I am new in this replication technology, do guide me if my step is wrong.)

Comment: Are we talking about Transactional Replication?

Comment: Yes. Transactional Replication.

Comment: So I come across this, it mention that "The principal difference in administering a peer-to-peer topology is that some changes require the system to be quiesced." So the "quiesced" information can get from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/administration/quiesce-a-replication-topology-replication-transact-sql-programming?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: The first step of "quiesced" is to "Stop activity on all published tables at all nodes.". Does this mean stop the application that CRUD the database? Beside stop the application, is that any other way to  "Stop activity on all published tables at all nodes." on the database level?

Comment: No. Maybe you have to find a different approach and skip Transactional Replication

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, this is the problem with Transactional Replication: every time you change something you need to recreate the publisher and the subscription.

I think your three steps are right.